# PHP Orderby a number saved as text on database

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to order a list of users by their mycred balance (integer) but this value is saved as string on database

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'mycred_default',
        'order'   => 'desc'
);                  

$users = get_users( $args );
```

How can I convert this string to integer before the query? or can I do it inside the query?

Comment: is this `mycred_default` a meta field?  You need to look at a `meta_query`

Comment: @HowardE yes, it is, but meta_query wouldn't still give me the same error because I'm not changing the value type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using meta_value_num could solve the issue

```
$args = [
    'meta_key' => 'mycred_default',
    'orderby'  => [ 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC' ],
    'order'    => 'desc',
];

$users = get_users( $args );
```